# How to detect facial angles?

Tags: opencv, numpy, machine-learning

I have over 2000 grayscale images with 96x96 pixel dimensions in numpy. I have (x,y) coordinated of facial key points such as left_eye_center, right_eye_center, nose_center, mouth_left, mouth_right etc..

Many of the faces in the dataset are tilted either left or right or up or down. So I would like to find out the facial orientation angles towards the camera.

Is there any library to detect this? I looked into opencv but it seems to do only facial detection not orientation.

Answer (score 1):

cmon, it's just plain maths:

```
    double eyeXdis = eye_r.x - eye_l.x;
    double eyeYdis = eye_r.y - eye_l.y;
    double angle   = atan(eyeYdis/eyeXdis);
    double degree  = angle*180/CV_PI;
```

[edit:]

it seems, what you're looking for is actually "head pose estimation" (or "posit")

you would need a (primitive) 3d head model, get the corresponding 3d points for your landmarks once, and then for each image find the 2d landmarks in the image, and get a rotation/translation vector from solvPnP() with that.

Comment: Great for x orientation. how about for y axes (faces looking up and down)??

Comment: hehe, not covered here ;) (you asked about tilted left or right)

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the training data into 3 labels (left, center, right) and then use it with your machine learning algorithm of choice to learn the 3 classes. If you're using opencv you can e.g. use HaarCascadeClassifiers (I once had a project where I used it to classify orientations). But really, anything works. You only need to extend it from binary classification (face detection) to multiclass classification (face orientation).

Comment: My network models prediction results far worse for oriented faces in x and y axis. This is why I want to detect angles and apply the theta to the results

Comment: Well. You can do that (it would obviously work). Or you can change the network to consider multiple classes. If your *ultimate* goal is detecting faces, then your new network will give you better "yes/no" results while even giving you more information "yes - and face is looking to the left". It depends on what you want to do.